# Bootstrap modal onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, bootstrap-modal

Does a bootstrap modal have an onload event? I want to call a http GET request when the modal is opened to populate the modal with data from a rest api. I have a form in the modal and I have called the GET function on the onload event of the form, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agent details:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

<form onload="getData()" style= "font-size: 16pt">
```

Comment: Please, read the documentation thoroughly before asking questions here. It's not that we don't want to help, it's just that we want you to try to do it yourself first.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), you can listen to the show or shown events.

From The Documentation:

> show.bs.modal => This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
>
> shown.bs.modal => This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Comment: you're a better typist than me :)

Answer (score 5):

What I've found to be the best way to do this is to add the onclick attribute to the html element that calls the modal.

```
<button type="button" onclick="PopulateAddModal()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal">Add</button>
```

Then in your javascript..

```js
    function PopulateAddModal() {
      //do stuff here...
      }
```

This will ensure that your code is ran as soon as the modal is called. Otherwise, the javascript code will not run until the modal has completely finished it's "fade-in" animation.